# If I had/have any questions, I'll ask

Tags: tense, verbs

Someone gave me a document to read. I said:

> I’ll read it. If I (had/have) any questions, I’ll ask.

Reading it will happen in future, and further questions will be asked after the doc is read.

Which verb goes here the best? Which one is completely wrong?

Comment: What do you think? Which word would you use?

Comment: *If I **have** any questions, I’ll ask* (refers to a "possible future"). *If I **had** any questions, I **would** ask* (refers to "timeless" alternate reality). *If I **had** any questions, I **would have asked*** (refers to "counterfactual past").

Comment: @RonaldSole I think `have`, but I don’t know why `had` seems somehow correct but when I get another sentence in my mind, like, `If I play the game, I’ll let you know.` or `If I get to play the game, I’ll let you know.`

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see. So, `If I had any questions, would ask.` is suggesting that right now, I don’t have any questions but if I had, I would ask. The third sentence that you said seems odd to me; Shouldn’t it be `If I had had any questions, would’ve asked.`?

Comment: We *could* use Past Perfect *(I had had)* there, but it's not *necessary*. I suspect that in real language (spoken) contexts, we more often use that form EITHER if the first instance of ***had*** is contracted *(I'd had)* OR if it's being given heavy stress for emphasis (where *If I **had** had any questions...* strongly implies that would have been *very* unlikely). If my example seems "odd" to you, you should spend more time listening to how native speakers actually talk, rather than focusing on what written "language teaching" texts tell you we *should* say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Absolutely. But for example in exams like IELTS, they focus on these kind of stuff, right? If not, then I can really switch the focus to a kind of a style like that, focusing on what native speakers use...

Comment: If my experience on ELL has taught *me* anything, it's that IELTS courses are more about passing exams than learning how native Anglophones actually use the language. Specifically, if you want to pass an IELTS exam, you have to use Perfect forms far more often than the average native Anglophone! I could sum it up by saying the successful IELTS student will should try to use the Perfect *whenever it's **possible***, whereas the average native Anglophone is more likely to use it *when it **can't be avoided***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Absolutely. Thanks for that. I honestly wouldn’t wonder what an Anglophone means by using unconventional grammar. I understand that all the natives use their languages different, I mean, so do we in our language. Exactly, IELTS is all about the conventions as far as I know but of course, natives do it differently and without consciousness. Thanks for your explanations. I really do it appreciate it.